# Can Design & Implementation sections be combined in a project report?

Tags: thesis, masters, writing

I'm writing a postrgraduate project report on a system I've built. It is not designed with the user in mind, it is a backend system to a simple web application.

I'm struggling to separate the Design chapter from the Implementation chapter in my report, as I didn't so much design the system as build it as I went, changing how it was built depending on issues I encountered during implementation.

Is it possible to add all design and implementation information under one chapter, as they are fairly intertwined, or is it necessary to separate them?

---

### Edit

I have solved my problem; the Design chapter is the idea and outline you had in the beginning of what you would like to create, with the various components you think you'll use, and the Implementation chapter includes all the issues that cropped up along the way, creating the need to change the original design.

Thanks for all your input!

Comment: I am not sure, but I am feeling like Academia.SE is not the correct place to ask this question. May be [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com) helps you more.

Comment: _I didn't so much design the system as build it as I went_ — **Don't do that.**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software documentation.

Comment: @JeffE but isn't that an important part of writing about software design research?

Comment: This seems like the type of question that only your advisor can answer.

Comment: If you've solved your own question, you should add the solution as an answer (note that you *can* accept your own answer if it's the most helpful to you), not as an edit to the question. This way, other users can vote separately on the question and answer, and people who come across this post in the future (because they have the same problem!) can more clearly identify your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

The Design chapter is the idea and outline you had in the beginning of what you would like to create, with the various components you think you'll use, and the Implementation chapter includes all the issues that cropped up along the way, creating the need to change the original design.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you were given an assignment to **design and build a system** and then write a report to document your work. However, you decided not to do that assignment and instead you decided to **build a system skipping the design step**.

I would expect the person marking your report would see it as you did not complete the task as assigned. As JeffE's comment implies, there is a reason why you were given a task that included designing first then building.

I think you should ask your lecturer if what you have done is acceptable or if you must restart your assignment.